# Docker-Machine AWS Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-machine

I want to create a aws group for docker-machine.

Which policies do I have to this role when I want the full functionality of docker-machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal IAM policy for docker-machine is available at https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1655.